# Pushing Ctrl + F to change focus to input and display search

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I have the following Javascript/jQuery code that focuses on an input field.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70)) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#search').focus();
    }
})
```

However I want to make it that so that if the user presses Ctrl+F again after being in focus of the search field, it would open up the default browser search window.

My idea was to change the code to:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70)){
        if($('#search').not(":focus")) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("Search is not in focus");
            $('#search').focus();
        } else {
            console.log("Default action of CtrlF")
            return true;
        }
    }
})
```

But that did not work (it always thinks search is not in focus even though it is)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  window.addEventListener("keydown",function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70)){
        if($('#search').is(":focus")) {
            console.log("Default action of CtrlF")
            return true;
        } else {
          
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("Search is not in focus");
            $('#search').focus();
        }
    }
})
  

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="search" id="search" />
```

Comment: Isn't this just the opposite of my if/else? Why would this work and not mine

Comment: yeah i have just used  is(":focus")) instead of not(":focus"))